# Is it possible to change the last modification date for files?

Tags: php

is it possible to change the last modification date for files? My hosting account has been hacked today and scan shows a lot of different domains get compromised. This account has been scanned two months ago by my hosting company and everything was fine, but today I have noticed that someone added

```
eval(gzinflate(base64_decode
```

containing malicious code. I'm bit confuse now as the last modification dates for all of the files are ranging from various months and days within 2012 and 2013. 
Any ideas? 8-O

Comment: not very sure what you want to achieve, but modification date are updated when files are edit, even by a malware like you have. If you have a back up just restore it deleting everything is best option for you.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. See e.g. [How can I change the date modified/created of a file?](http://askubuntu.com/q/62492)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure for example on unix you can simply use "[touch](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/touch.1.asp)".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to change the modification date. If you tell me what platform your site is hosted on, I'll tell you how they could have done it.